# ionic 4 multi array in for loop

Tags: angular, ionic4

I need to use one `*ngFor` in ionic4.

This is my code,

```
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of data.name">
            <ion-checkbox mode="md"  [(ngModel)]="data.checked" value="0" ></ion-checkbox>
            <ion-label class="title-add">{{item}} </ion-label>
            <ion-label slot="end" class="ion-text-end price-add">
                <ion-text color="medium">+ {{prop}} ريال </ion-text>
            </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
```

I have two arrays

`data.name` and
`data.price`

I need to make it same loop in ion-item.
How can I make it?

API response:

```
male_addition: [
{
id: 33,
name: [
"pepsi",
"cola"
],
name_additions: "drinks",
price: [
"3",
"3"
],
type: 2,
male_id: 15,
details_id: 45,
created_at: "2020-02-28 16:16:18",
updated_at: "2020-02-28 16:16:18"
}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should map your two arrays assuming they're always associated with each other into a new array of objects that are of type `{name: string; price: number;}`.

Do something like this,

```
this.namePriceArray = this.male_addition.flatMap(data => 
                                    data.name.map((n, i) => ({name: n, price: data.price[i]})));
```

And then you can use `this.namePriceArray` in your `*ngFor` inside of `<ion-item>`.

```
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of namePriceArray">
            <ion-checkbox mode="md"  [(ngModel)]="data.checked" value="0" ></ion-checkbox>
            <ion-label class="title-add">{{item.name}} {{item.price}}</ion-label>
            <ion-label slot="end" class="ion-text-end price-add">
                <ion-text color="medium">+ {{prop}} ريال </ion-text>
            </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
```

Comment: hi, thank u for  help but u can help me more
it's not work with me

Comment: What's the issue you see when you try this solution?

Comment: it's worked fine but i forget tell u data in loop by  category

Comment: every id have male_addition array  i need show name  only in male_addition  array 
now he show all data not  by id

Comment: What are you attempting to achieve? What do you mean by data in loop by category? I don't see the word category in the API response.

Comment: i mean male_addition  by id now he get all male_addition

Comment: how can i get male_addition  by id not all

Comment: You can also map the id into the same object `this.namePriceArray = this.male_addition.flatMap(data => 
                                    data.name.map((n, i) => ({id: data.id, name: n, price: data.price[i]})));`